# Idiomatic way to serve an internal server and a php directory under the same domain name with apache

Tags: proxy, directory, apache2

I tried many things since yesterday with no good result.
Here is the situation I have an internal server listening on port 4000 and a wordpress directory located in /var/www/html/wordpress.

I use

```
ProxyPass / http://locahost:4000/
```

to handle the first server but I can't figure out how to serve my wordpress so that

```
http://example.ext/wordpress
```

go the wordpress directory and not the internal server listening on port 4000.

A hint or anything more than that would be highly appreciated,

thx a lot for your answers

Comment: You very also likely want to have a ProxyPassReverse line (same args) in addition to the ProxyPass line. This is in addition to ezra-s's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual ProxyPass directive is telling Apache to proxy everything to that backend, but the problem is easy to solve.

Before your actual ProxyPass directive add this one:

```
ProxyPass /wordpress !
```

This one will effectively tell Apache to not proxy /wordpress and whatever comes after it, as in /wordpress/something, etc..

Just keep in  mind that most specific paths should be defined before the more global paths, that's why I say you should add the directive I told you "before" the one you already have.

In case of any doubts here is the reference page:
[ProxyPass Reference URL](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)